# Remove duplicates in the query set

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a query set like the one below which depicts the albums and songs associated with those albums. The model name is `UserSongs`

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'album': 'Sri', 'song': 'in the end','release': 2017},
{'id': 2, 'album': 'Adi', 'song': 'cafe mocha','release': 2016}, 
{'id': 3, 'album': 'Shr', 'song': 'smooth criminal','release': 2016}, 
{'id': 4, 'album': 'Mouse', 'song': 'trooper','release': 2017},
{'id': 5, 'album': 'Mouse', 'song': 'my mobile','release': 2015},
{'id': 6, 'album': 'Sri', 'song': 'my office','release': 2018},
{'id': 7, 'album': 'Sri', 'song': 'null','release': null},
{'id': 8, 'album': 'Mouse', 'song': 'null','release': null}]>
```

In the backend, I'm converting the query set into a list. See code below:

```
albums_songs = UserSongs.objects.filter(album__in = 
['Sri','Mouse']).values('albums','songs')
list_albums_songs = list(albums_songs)
```

I'm sending this list to the front-end for displaying it in table.`Sri`,`Mouse` have multiple entries since they have released multiple songs. In the front end, these songs are displayed in a table with album and songs as entries. Each item in the query set is displayed as one row. Like the one below.

```
Album   Songs
Sri     in the end
Adi     cafe mocha
Adi     null
Shr     smooth criminal
Mouse   trooper
Mouse   my mobile
Sri     my office 
Sri     null 
Mouse   null
```

But in the table, `null` entry for the song is also displayed. I don't want to display that null entry for only `Sri`,`Mouse`. I want to diaplay the `song=null` doe `Adi`.I can remove it after converting into list and iterating over the list. But that is costly. I believe that we can do it in django query itself. Something like, if album is Sri or Mouse, then check for song = null and don't get that entry.

Or after getting the query set, before converting into list, can we remove those items from query set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `isnull` filter:

```
albums_songs = UserSongs.objects.filter(album__in=['Sri','Mouse'], songs__isnull=False).values('albums','songs')
```

EDIT: With the new requirements in your updated question, you should use the `exclude` method instead:

```
albums_songs = UserSongs.objects.exclude(album__in=['Sri','Mouse'], songs__isnull=True).values('albums','songs')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, blhsing. I have got what you are doing. What if I have so many albums, i can't write each album in a list. Also, I have edited the question, please check.

Comment: @SriHarsha Do you want all the albums or some of them in your query ?

Comment: @SriHarsha I've updated my answer for your new requirements.

Comment: @blhsing That works like a charm. I have changed the `is null` to true as soon as you have posted your previous answer. But that you for the answer.